# XBox One Exiting Hulu with Logitech Harmony Companion All in One Remote Control

Tags: controllers, xbox-one

Basically, the XBox One is our entertainment center. I bought the Harmony Companion remote for my wife, as that is easier than a controller.

Works great, except, once you're in the XBox One Hulu app, there's no button I can figure out to exit Hulu (say to get into the XBox One Youtube app for example).  Same with Netflix. But not the same with Youtube, you can exit that with the "return" button.

What am I missing?!! With the XBox One controller, you have to do with it the XBox button.

Comment: Might help to include which harmony remote you have, the express or the "IR" remote. Either way, it seems you can [customize buttons](https://support.myharmony.com/en-us/customizing-physical-buttons-on-your-remote), but I'm not sure if xbox has a predefined list of actions (such as "press Xbox button" or "close active app") but maybe that's worth a shot?

Comment: @Dpeif Thanks for your response. I called it the "Harmony Companion remote". The Harmony Companion remote is really a remote, a hub, an IR blaster and an app. Frankly, I don't think the issue is the hardware as such. The hardware can generate IR *AND* RF control signals. The issue is really the Hulu Xbox app. You can't exit it "naturally" without an "Xbox button". You're basically captive. Can't believe Microsoft allows that as a design choice.

Comment: No offense, but there are controls to exit apps when you use the *intended controller for the platform*. So yes, the issue would be with your hardware, sorry. [Xbox sells it's own remote.](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/pdp-talon-media-remote-for-xbox-one-black/5377800.p?skuId=5377800&ref=212&loc=1&extStoreId=1478&ref=212&loc=1&gclsrc=aw.ds&ds_rl=1266837&ds_rl=1268709&ds_rl=1268661&gclid=Cj0KCQjwv8nqBRDGARIsAHfR9wD3KJJwk3Rkb_JXODur-6WndvEWKyRwydbcCdbu786SDALbuIr6eQIaAsbfEALw_wcB)

Comment: @Dpeif - So your comment seems to say "Don't buy or use universal remotes" I suppose that's an answer.  And no, it's not a hardware issue.  The functionality is fine under Youtube, for example. Unfortunately, Hulu and Netflix chose not to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

On the Logitech remote, press guide, go over and you will see a second page, then you can go to the Home Screen.